# adding two arrays in python using for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

In the output i can view two outputs were printed

```
from numpy import *
a=array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print(a)
b=array([7,8,9,1,2,3])
for x in (a,6):
    print(a+b)
```

Comment: The loop runs twice, once with `x = a` and then `x = 6`, thus calling`print(a+b)` twice.

Comment: Okay; what is your *question*?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  Do you want to merely add `a` and `b` coordinate-wise?  If so, you can just do `a+b`.  You don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Yes, It was a task given to me to add arrays in a for loop.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i want the ouptut to be executed once not twice.

Comment: @unil Hi, what can i do to print it only once?

Comment: `for i, x in enumerate(a):
    print(x + b[i])` not sure what output do you expect and why do you need to do it with a for loop?

Comment: `for x in (a, 6):` means the loop runs twice: once with `x` equal to `a`, and once with `x` equal to `6`. The number `6` here has nothing to do with the length of the arrays, and the loop has nothing to do with how the arrays get added together. The addition works on each element because they are special Numpy arrays with custom logic for doing that. When you add `a` to `b`, it adds the arrays element-wise; when you add `6` to `b`, it adds 6 to each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
from numpy import *
a=array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print('Value of a is: ',a)
b=array([7,8,9,1,2,3])
print('Value of b is: ',b)
c=[]

for x in range(len(a)):
    #print (a[x]+b[x])
    c.append(a[x]+b[x])

print('The sum of a+b is: ',c)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the for loop, just do it like this:

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
b=np.array([7,8,9,1,2,3])
print(a+b)

#Output
[ 8 10 12  5  7  9]
```

Comment: Hi @Nathan Thomas I need to add them using for loop so i tried in that way but output i got is [1 2 3 4 5 6]
[ 8 10 12  5  7  9]
[ 8 10 12  5  7  9]

Comment: What do you mean by you need to add them using a for loop?

Comment: I need to add two arrays using for loop so i executed that code but the output was printed twice though i have mentioned the range.

Comment: Why do you need to use a for loop?

Comment: So the answer I provided is probably the best way to do it. Using a for loop isn't best practice for this kind of operation, you could say that this answer is more "pythonic" than a for loop. But if your task states that you MUST use a for loop, try: ```[i+j for i,j in zip(a,b)]```

Comment: @NathanThomas Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Also ensure to check the length of the two arrays, else you will run into ValueError.

```
from numpy import *
a=array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(a)
b=array([7,8,9,1,2])
print(b)

len_a = len(a)
len_b = len(b)
if len_a == len_b:
    print(a+b)
else:
    print("length of array_a = %d, len of array_b = %d, cannot add two arrays") % (len_a, len_b)
```